# .NET: Running a server crashes with SocketException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm running a .NET service in debug mode.
Once the program reaches the lines:

```
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args, null).Build();
        if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug") || Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT) 
        {
            host.Run();
        }
```

it throws a SocketException exception.

You can see it here:
[image]

I tried to search in the Internet but I didn't find anything that can help.
Any idea?

Comment: Entering debug mode attaches a debugger to the runtime. This, in turn, may pause the thread that handles the web sockets. I haven't run into this issue because I use JetBrains Rider (which runs perfectly with Dotnet/SignalR), but there must be a configuration option that resumes the socket connections

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to stop this error.

Go to "Services" and stop the service "World Wide Web Publishing Service".